# How does the null cone relate to the Minkowski diagram?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, causality

I appreciate, this may be self explanatory or a silly question. I have seen derivations for the Minkowski diagram (Penrose) and don't understand if the null cone is just the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case or if they are unrelated.

Comment: They are related: in units of $c=1$, Minkowski diagrams have the null vectors along the lines 45 deg. to the axes... The Minkowski diagrams are essentially 1+1 dimensional representations of the light cone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is more than you want or were looking for.
But anyway...

The Minkowski diagram is firstly a **position-vs-time graph**,
sometimes drawn with the time-axis running upward and the space-axis running horizontally.
Nevertheless, it is a position-vs-time graph.

With our current understanding,
the **"PHY101 position-vs-time graph"** is actually
a low-relative-speed low-time-resolution approximation to the Minkowski diagram.

The null-cone (sometimes called the "light cone")--part of it shown below as a dashed-blue line--can be interpreted as the set of events that can be signaled by a light-signal emitted by an origin event [a firecracker explosion], plus the set of events that can signal ["trigger"] the origin event via a light-signal .

[image: robphy-Minkowski-diagram]

The red curve marks the set of all events "1-tick" from the origin event along inertial worldlines. That is, if folks meeting at the origin event and travelled with all possible allowed velocities [limited by the upper bound of the maximum speed of signal propagation], their events marking "1 tick later on their wristwatches" lie on the red curve (a hyperbola, which plays the role of the circle in the Minkowski spacetime geometry of special relativity).

The null cone is asymptotic to that future hyperbola (a future hyperboloid when the other spatial dimensions are included).

It's called the "null" cone because this "circle" is used to assign magnitudes to vectors from the origin. To vectors from the vertex along the null-cone, the "square-magnitude" (sometimes called the "square-interval" for a spacetime-displacement-vector) is zero. For those unit vectors like the one along the time axis pointing inside (called "timelike", along the worldlines of inertial observers with allowed velocities) are assigned +1 and those outside like the space axis (called "spacelike") are assigned -1, by a conventional choice of "[metric]" signature" $(+,-,-,-)$.

In addition, if each observer drew their own version of the Minkowski diagram,
the various observer worldlines would be "rotated", but the null cone directions
would be the same... this is the invariance of the speed of light.

[image: robphy-Minkowski-diagram-approx]

Because the speed of light is very large compared to the familiar everyday speeds we are used to on a PHY 101 position-vs-time graph, this null cone is appears very close (almost indistinguishable) to the space-axes when using typical PHY101 axis-ranges.
The hyperbola marking "1 tick" of wristwatches appears to be a vertical line,
on the time-scale used on the typical axes.
(When the 30 m/s observer meets the "t=1 second" vertical line,
that observer's wristwatch actually reads about $(1-(5\times 10^{-15}))$ seconds!)

But since we (for practical reasons) ignore that "tiny" discrepancy,
we don't see the hyperbola and its asymptote [the null cone],
and thus, we don't intuitively [with our everyday common sense]
appreciate the real structure of spacetime geometry.